# Ruby - IO.read('file_path') returns empty string, but I know file has content

Tags: ruby, file, rspec, io

I'm trying to write an RSpec test that confirms an error message is sent to stderr when a problem occurs.  My solution was to have stderr output to a file:

```
$stderr = File.new(File.join(@output_path, 'stderr.txt'), 'w')
```

Eventually when my test causes an error to occur, the stderr.txt file contains this string:

```
envelope_evaluation.rb: Could not initialize variables
```

But, when I try to extract this string from stderr.txt via this line:

```
contents = IO.read("#{@output_path}/stderr.txt")
```

The contents variable is always empty. Am I missing an IO step?

NEW EDIT

After the discussion below, I've cleaned my code up a bit, but I'm still experiencing an empty string result.  When I redirect $stderr to my error file, I now am doing it in read/write mode:

```
$stderr = File.new("#{@output_path}/stderr.txt", 'w+')
```

After that, my envelope_evaluation.rb script executes and the stderr.txt file is populated with an error message.  Since $stderr now has read rights, I then get its contents via:

```
$stderr.flush
contents = $stderr.read
```

Unfortunately the 'contents' variable is still empty though.

Comment: Just put a line `$stderr.close`, before reading into `contents`. or after `$stderr = File.new(File.join(@output_path, 'stderr.txt'), 'w')`.

Comment: Is there any reason you are doing `File.join(@output_path, 'stderr.txt')` in one place and `"#{@output_path}/stderr.txt"` in another? That looks very bad.

Comment: I'm wondering the same question @sawa asked. Also, you can also do `$stderr.flush` before you attempt to read it, if you plan to write more to `$stderr` later in the script.

Comment: @sawa, I have no reason for showing them differently at this time.  I've tried 20 different solutions and just ended up with different looking code as a result.

Comment: did you try what I said ?

Comment: Unfortunately $stderr.close and $stderr.flush are not working for me either.

Comment: Because you just open the file *write* mode -> `File.new(File.join(@output_path, 'stderr.txt'), 'w')`. But didn't write into it.. Did you? and also you are also overriding the file `File.join(@output_path, 'stderr.txt')`. Didn't you ?

Comment: My envelope_evaluation.rb script writes error messages to stderr, for example:  $stderr.puts 'error message'. It shows up in the file too.  I just tested IO.read with a different file and it was able to read in the string successfully, so there's definitely something weird going on with stderr.  As far as the override, I actually don't know.  This is a little bit out of my wheelhouse as I haven't done any IO in Ruby before.

Comment: Dear.. you have a file `error.txt`. Again, you are writing `File.new('error.txt', 'w')`. Don't you think here you are overwriting here...?? This is the reason you are loosing the content.

Comment: Arup, thank you for being patient with me.  This is definitely helpful even if I haven't figured it all out yet.  I'll add an edit up above with some of the new code.  I changed the mode to w+ so the file can be written and read.

Comment: I think I understand your question now.  I am intentionally overriding the 'stderr.txt' at the beginning of my test unit because it needs to be cleared, otherwise I would be seeing messages from a previous test run.  The $stderr = File.new(File.join(@output_path, 'stderr.txt'), 'w') line is contained in a before{} bracket, so it should clear then be repopulated when I run the script.